# libpqxx postgresql utf8 strings

Tags: postgresql, unicode, utf-8

Does it possible insert into database table (based on postgresql) utf8 (unicode) string?

```
pqxx::work tr(*_conn.get(), "notify");
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "INSERT INTO tbl (msg) VALUES ('" << msg << "');";
tr.exec(ss.str());
tr.commit();
```

I want message content will be for example `ｷｴｵｲｳｶｸｹｺｻｼｽｾｿﾀﾁﾂﾃｱ`. But `exec` method waits `char` string, not `wchar`. How can I encode utf8 string to pass it into the query?
Additional question: how can I encode `utf8` string using `wchar_t` type? I assume that `wchar` type represents 2-bytes symbols, but utf8 may contain up to 6-bytes symbols.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to convert wide char string into utf8 like this:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv;
std::string u8str = conv.to_bytes(msg);
```

or this way:

```
std::wstring wmsg_text = L"ｷｴｵｲｳｶｸｹｺｻｼｽｾｿﾀﾁﾂﾃｱ";
char buffer[100] = { 0 };
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wmsg_text.data(), wmsg_text.size(),   buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, NULL, NULL);
```

Of course after obtaining the string from database it's necessarily to execute:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv;
std::wstring u8str = conv.from_bytes(message);
```